# Household Names Rebus Puzzle

Tags: wordplay, rebus

Try to solve these rebus puzzles

[image]
**Solved**

> 1.Yes
>
> 2.Yes
>
> 3.Yes
>
> 4.Yes
>
> 5.Yes
>
> 6.Yes

*Source: Google Images*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my answer:

For 1 maybe

> Volkswagen? (Volt-Wagon)

2 is

> Tesla (tes-la ("romance" for A))

3 is

> Oreo (Or-Rio, a bit far fetched though :p)

4 is

> Nintendo (nin- (50/5=ten) - do). At the begening was looking for some formula like length/volume, but realise it was a operation with roman numbers

5 is

> Pizza hut (peace-ha-hut)

6 is

> Disney (dis-knee)

Comment: Those are correct!

Comment: darn i had #1 but thought it was a household brand so didn't post

Comment: Yay :). Nice rebus ;)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie (A tip: don't give the checkmark for a few hours, even 12-24, so that your puzzle receives more attention.)